# Who’s the child with the soldiers in "Man of Steel"?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In the scene where Clark surrenders to the Kryptonians, among the soldiers behind him is a child in military armour. Does anyone know who that is?

[image: group of soldiers, including a kid]

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 8):

That is [Major Carrie Farris](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0770828/characters/nm3542919), played by [Christina Wren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5wE7.jpg).

Interestingly, her character in the [DCEU](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Carrie_Farris) is a nod to Carol Ferris, a love interest of Hal Jordan, the Green Lantern.

[image: Major Carrie Farris in army uniform, carrying paper files]

Answer (score 3):

Looking back at the movie I figured it out. Who I thought was a kid was actually the General’s aide, kitted up standing next to the much taller men around her makes her look like a kid.

Comment: [Easy mistake to make.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2k9GQK0b_g#t=0m23s)